# Updating code from 2012: -[UITableView switchToFavImageView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm working on my Funny Pics app now. The last update was 2012. I did some work to update it and ran across an issue I can't resolve. There's a favorites section and you can no longer click on the favorite thumbnails to bring them full screen. In my ImageDownloadButton class that displays the thumbnail, I have the following code that should show the full screen when the thumbnail is clicked, but it's not working.

```
- (void)buttonClicked { 
UIView *myView = [[[self superview] superview] superview]; 
id gridId = [(UITableView *)myView delegate]; 
if([(NSObject *)gridId respondsToSelector:@selector(switchToFavImageView:)]) { 
[(id<ImageDownloadButtonDelegate>)gridId switchToFavImageView:uid]; 
} 
}
```

In my FavGridTableViewController, it implements ImageDownloadButtonDelegate and there's a switchToFavImageView method.

The error is [UITableView switchToFavImageView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

edit:
UIView *myView = [[[self superview] superview] superview];
returns a UITableViewWrapperView.  Calling delegate on that returns a UITableView.  I used to be able to use ImageDownloadButtonDelegate which FavGridTableViewController implements, but it no longer works.

Comment: It looks like you set your delegate to a UITableView, which I'm guessing is not what you were trying to do. Can you post where you set your delegate and your implementation of the delegate method?

Comment: Here's my interface code for FavGridTableViewController:  @interface FavGridTableViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, ImageDownloadButtonDelegate, MPAdViewDelegate> {

Comment: I don't have an implementation of the delegate method. That's provided by Apple's UITableViewDelegate I think.  This code wasn't originally written by me but I've been bug fixing.  I can zip up the project and send it to you if that would help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are relying on the view structure of a UIButton to be a certain way:

```
UIView *myView = [[[self superview] superview] superview];
```

That is not allowed. The internal structure of a UIButton (and other views) can be changed by Apple at any time, and certainly has changed between IOS6 and IOS7.

Store the gridId delegate in an explicit field of your custom button instead.